# MIME type for msgpack?

Tags: http, data-serialization, msgpack

[msgpack](http://msgpack.org/) seems to be an extremely fast, if extremely new format for data serialisation. Does it have a recognised MIME type yet? If not, what should be used in the interim?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to a quick Google the overwhelming answer is `application/x-msgpack`. However, I can't find an authorative source.

Comment: And according to an overwhelmingly quick Google search, this is now the first result, so thank you!

Comment: The goal is to use `application/msgpack` see https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack/issues/194

Comment: I would go with `application/msgpack`

Answer (score 53):

From the Wikipedia page on [Media type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type#Unregistered_tree):

> According to RFC 6838 (published in January 2013 : https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6838), any use of types in the "x." tree is strongly discouraged. Media types with names beginning with "x-" are no longer considered to be members of this tree since January 2013.

So you can use `application/msgpack`.

Answer (score 1):

`application/x-msgpack` is probably the correct `MIME` header, however a small caution to future readers: relying on a `MIME` type for anything beyond high-level information is dangerous (at best) because the structure and meaning of the message is dynamic in nature.

Answer (score 0):

Application types:

- `application/msgpack`
- `application/x-msgpack`
- `application/*+msgpack`